# Find faces of a planar graph in python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, igraph

I'm trying to find the faces of a planar graph in python. I know [such a function exists in IGraphM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176057), the Mathematica interface to igraph, but I'm wondering if that was implemented only in that interface or the python igraph also has something similar.

If not, then please feel free to give me ideas for how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planar graph functionality only exists in [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#planar-graphs), not in the other interfaces of igraph. This is because IGraph/M uses parts of the [LEMON graph library](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) for this functionality, as well as code that's specifically written for IGraph/M.

You will get quicker answers to such questions if you ask at https://igraph.discourse.group/